# Beyond Radon-Nykodim: Besicovitch theorem

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, geometric-measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I found, with no reference, the following theorem which is called *Besicovitch derivation theorem*. Do you know any article/book where I can find this powerful result?

> Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ be an open set, $\mu,\nu$ be positive measures on $\Omega$. Then, for $\mu-e.a.\ x$ in the support of $\mu,$ 
>   $$\exists \ \ \lim_{\rho \to 0} \frac{\nu (B_\rho (x))}{\mu( B_\rho(x))}=:f(x)$$
>   moreover the Radon-Nykodim decomposition of $\nu$ is given by
>   $$\nu=f\mu+\nu^s$$
>   Finally, defining
>   $$E:=\biggl (\Omega-supp(\mu)\biggr ) \bigcup \{x: f(x)=\infty\}$$
>   we have
>   $$\mu(E)=0 \qquad \nu^s(\Omega - E)=0$$

Comment: There is a related theorem in Foland: Real Analysis Modern Techniques and Their Applications: page 99 Theorem 3.22. It is not exactly the theorem you stated.